# Como usar onClick no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eventos, onclick, eventos-do-mouse

Galera, estou batendo cabeça numa coisa:

Existe um código HTML, que faz um formulário. Neste formulário existe uma resposta que eu posso escolher entre **sim** e **não**. A resposta em baixo desta, fornece um campo, CASO você coloque **sim** na resposta acima, como justificativa.

O que eu quero fazer: Eu quero criar uma função no JS que quando eu selecionar o **sim** apareça este campo, e caso eu coloque **não** ele permaneça oculto.

Minha duvida: Como eu uso o JS? Como eu uso o `onClick`? Quero saber quais variáveis eu coloco e como posso fazer esse código, se eu coloco o id do **sim** e do **não**, como eu construo?

Desculpem muitas duvidas

Vi algo assim:

```
<script>
        const radio = document.querySelectorAll(".radioButton");
        const "element" = document.("");

        radio[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
            "".style.display = "block";
        });

        radio[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
            "".style.display = "none";
        });
 </script>
```

Mas não sei onde coloco cada coisa.. por exemplo, o que quero ocultar, onde coloco no codigo, uso id ou name.. onde eu coloco cada coisa

Comment: Caso, qualquer uma das respostas abaixo resolveu seu problema marque como aceita.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, você fez quase tudo só falta você criar dois elementos de entrada de opção e o elemento de entrada de texto:

```
<label for="yes">Sim</label><input id="yes" name="radios" class="radioButton" type="radio">
<label for="no">Não</label><input id="no" name="radios" class="radioButton" type="radio">
<br>
<input id="textField" type="text" style="display: none;">
```

Depois, acrescentar algumas coisas no seu código:

```
<script>

    const radio = document.querySelectorAll(".radioButton");
    const text = document.querySelector("#textField");

    radio[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
        text.style.display = "block";
    });

    radio[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
        text.style.display = "none";
    })
```

**Resultado**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <label for="yes">Sim</label><input id="yes" name="radios" class="radioButton" type="radio">
    <label for="no">Não</label><input id="no" name="radios" class="radioButton" type="radio">
    <br>
    <input id="textField" type="text" style="display: none;">

    <script>

        const radio = document.querySelectorAll(".radioButton");
        const text = document.querySelector("#textField");

        radio[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
            text.style.display = "block";
        });

        radio[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
            text.style.display = "none";
        })

 </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você usa `document.getElementById('id')` 
dentro da dos parênteses tu colaca a id que tu usou você só usa se for id exemplo `<div id="nome"></div>` dentro dos parênteses coloca nome pois foi o que tu usou enquanto as funções são usadas pra tu não ter que ficar usando o mesmo código várias vezes então vou dar exemplo de uma básica

```
function ola() {
 alert('Sei lá') }
dps tu pode chamar essa função no onclick de um botão 
Exemplo
<button type="button" onclick="ola()">Clique</button>
```